# Is it possible for an app to obtain the information about how long the user uses another app?

Tags: ios

In iOS, is it possible for an app to get the information about how long the user uses another app?

Answer (score 3):

In iOS each app runs in its own sandbox and cannot see data from other apps, even apps from the same publisher. An app can access special shared data, like photos from the album or contact data, but it is not possible for an app to directly access information like you have mentioned.

Comment: Not possible unless you jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. There is no way to fetch data from another app, this is part of the [App Sandboxing principle](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/).